# Python индекс ближайшего значения в массиве

Tags: python

Имеется ли в Python функция которая позволяет выполнить поиск в отсортированном числовом массиве/списке получив при этом ближайший индекс, если в массиве такого значения нет?

На примере C# это выглядит следующим образом:

```
  List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 3, 6, 8 };
            int res = ~list.BinarySearch(2);//1
```

Т.е., в аналогичном массиве/списке Python

```
arr = [1, 3, 6, 8]
a = arr.index(3)  # Результат работы функции будет 1
a = arr.index(2)  # Результат работы функции будет array.index(x): x not in array
```

Answer (score 1):

Двоичный поиск реализован в модуле [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

arr = [1, 3, 3, 6, 8]
print(bisect_left(arr, 2)) # 1
print(bisect_left(arr, 3)) # 1

print(bisect_right(arr, 2)) # 1
print(bisect_right(arr, 3)) # 3
```

`bisect_left` вернет количество элементов меньших чем искомый, `bisect_right` - меньших либо равных.

Comment: Уважаемый extrn Спасибо за ответ